Use function first parameter value as key for accessing a type property
I have a function that accepts two parameters, the first one is the key I want to access from a given type and the second one should be the values that this given type and key have, for example, given the following type:
type Example = {
  letter: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  number: 1 | 2 | 3;
}

I want these scenarios to be VALID:
myFunction<Example>('letter', 'a');
myFunction<Example>('letter', 'c');
myFunction<Example>('number', 1);
myFunction<Example>('number', 2);

And these scenarios to be INVALID:
myFunction<Example>('letter', 1);
myFunction<Example>('letter', 2);
myFunction<Example>('number', 'b');
myFunction<Example>('number', 'c');

Currently I have something that looks similar to this:
type MyProperties = {
  size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
  type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
}

/**
 * The second parameter type is not valid because it is accepting all the
 * possible values 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'a', 'b' or 'c' even when
 * the key is 'size' for example.
 */
function testing<P>( key: keyof P, value: P[typeof key] ) {
  //
}

// The current scenario gives me the following:

testing<MyProperties>('size', 'small');      // OK
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'medium');     // OK
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'large');      // OK
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'a');          // OK.
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'b');          // OK.
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'c');          // OK.
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'something');  // BAD.

// But what I really want to achieve is:

testing<MyProperties>('size', 'small');      // OK
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'medium');     // OK
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'large');      // OK
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'a');          // BAD because 'a' is not a "size" valid value even tho is valid for P[typeof key].
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'b');          // BAD because 'b' is not a "size" valid value even tho is valid for P[typeof key].
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'c');          // BAD because 'c' is not a "size" valid value even tho is valid for P[typeof key].
testing<MyProperties>('size', 'something');  // BAD because 'something' is not a "size" valid value.

Is this even possible?

• You have a typo in Example. Please [edit] to fix it. • Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz wow, this is exactly what I wanted! Can you please add this response and explain it to me so I can accept it? Thank you so much!

TypeScript currently lacks the ability to have partial generic type argument inference, as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#26242. So while conceptually it would be nice to write
declare function myFunction<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: T[K]): void;

you can't call that in a way that lets you manually specify T but has the compiler infer K:
myFunction<Example>('letter', 'a'); // error!
//         ~~~~~~~
// Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.(2558)

You could call it by manually specifying both T and K:
myFunction<Example, 'letter'>('letter', "a"); // okay

but that's annoying/redundant.

Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#26242, you'll need to work around it. In general, people work around that by currying:
declare function myFunction<T extends object>(): <K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: T[K]) => void;
myFunction<Example>()('letter', "a"); // okay

This works but involves an extra function call you don't want. Still, if you need the function to still be generic in K after specifying T, you have to do something like this.

But maybe you don't need the function to be generic in K. Since K is only meant to be one of a union of types, you can try representing the function's parameters as a union of tuple-typed rest parameters:
type ArgsForMyFunction<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [k: K, v: T[K]] }[keyof T];
declare function myFunction<T extends object>(...[k, v]: ArgsForMyFunction<T>): void;

Here, the ArgsForMyFunction<T> is a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. That's where you write a mapped type over a set of keys and then index into it with the same set of keys, producing a union of properties.  If you have a type function like F<K>, then type G<K> = {[P in K]: F<P>}[K] distributes F over unions in K, such that G<K1 | K2> is F<K1> | F<K2>.
So, in ArgsForMyFunction<T>, the parameter list tuple [k: K, v: T[K]] is distributed over the union in keyof T.  Like so:
type Example = {
  letter: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  number: 1 | 2 | 3;
}    
type ExampleArgs = ArgsForMyFunction<Example>;
// type ExampleArgs = [k: "number", v: 2 | 1 | 3] | [k: "letter", v: "a" | "b" | "c"]

type TestArgs = ArgsForMyFunction<{ a: string, b: number, c: boolean }>;
// type TestArgs = [k: "a", v: string] | [k: "b", v: number] | [k: "c", v: boolean]

And that means myFunction() is now only generic in T and you don't need currying:
myFunction<Example>('letter', 'a'); // okay
myFunction<Example>('letter', 'c'); // okay
myFunction<Example>('number', 1); // okay
myFunction<Example>('number', 2); // okay

myFunction<Example>('letter', 1); // error
myFunction<Example>('letter', 2); // error
myFunction<Example>('number', 'b'); // error
myFunction<Example>('number', 'c'); // error

which is what you wanted.
Playground link to code

Your’re awesome! Thank you so much for this.

There are a couple of solutions:

Add additional generic constraint for keys:
Pros: keeps function signature more or less as-is
Cons: need to define key both as a type variable and as a function parameter.


function testing<P, K extends keyof P>( key: K, value: P[K] ) {
    //
}


testing<MyProperties, "size">("size", "small");      // OK
testing<MyProperties, "size">("size", "medium");     // OK
testing<MyProperties, "size">("size", "large");      // OK
testing<MyProperties, "size">("size", "a");          // BAD.
testing<MyProperties, "size">("size", "b");          // BAD.
testing<MyProperties, "size">("size", "c");          // BAD.
testing<MyProperties, "size">("size", "something");  // BAD.


If you are 100% certain you will use testing only with MyProperties, this makes for a shorter generics constraint definition:
Pros: no need to specify generic type variable
Cons: limits the function usage only to MyProperties.


function testing<Key extends keyof MyProperties>( key: Key, value: MyProperties[Key] ) {
    //
}

testing("size", "small");      // OK
testing("size", "medium");     // OK
testing("size", "large");      // OK
testing("size", "a");          // BAD.
testing("size", "b");          // BAD.
testing("size", "c");          // BAD.
testing("size", "something");  // BAD.


Merge function parameters into a single object on which tighter generics constraints can be applied:
Pros: can pass in multiple key/value pairs from a single generic object
Cons: increased complexity.


/** 
 * Utility type that helps create a type where exactly one of the properties of
 * an interface (can be any property) is required to exist.
 * Inspired by `RequireAtleastOne` from MS docs:
 * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-certificates/requireatleastone?view=azure-node-latest
 */
type RequireExactlyOne<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & { [NoK in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never }
}[keyof T]

type KeyValue<P> = RequireExactlyOne<{ [K in keyof P]: P[K] }>

function testing<P>(kv: KeyValue<P>) {
  const key = Object.keys(kv)[0] as keyof typeof kv; // access first key
  const value = kv[key]; // access first value
  // ...
}

testing<MyProperties>({ size: "small" });           // OK
testing<MyProperties>({ size: "medium" });          // OK
testing<MyProperties>({ size: "large" });           // OK
testing<MyProperties>({ });                         // BAD.
testing<MyProperties>({ size: "a" });               // BAD.
testing<MyProperties>({ size: "b" });               // BAD.
testing<MyProperties>({ size: "c" });               // BAD.
testing<MyProperties>({ size: "something" });       // BAD.
testing<MyProperties>({ size: "large", type: "a" });// BAD.


You can make a function like this:
function testing<P>( key: keyof P, value: P[typeof key] ) {
 const isValidSize = key === "size";
 const isValidLetter = key === "letter"
 if(isValidSize || isValidLetter){
  const VALUES_SIZE = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
  const VALUES_LETTER = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  if(isValidLetter){
   if(VALUES_LETTER.includes(value)){...}
   else{console.log("...")}
  }
  if(isValidSize){
   if(VALUES_SIZE.includes(value)){...}
   else{console.log("...")}
  }
 }else{
  console.log("...")
 }
}

for types:
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
type Example {
  letter: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
  number: 1 | 2 | 3;
};
type ExampleValues = Values<Example>;


Sorry if I wasn’t clear but what I really want is a TypeScript auto complete for the second parameter.

@RafaelBerro ```typescript
type Values = T[keyof T];
type Example {
letter: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
number: 1 | 2 | 3;
};
type ExampleValues = Values;


@RafaelBerro I may really not understand. Perhaps the second answer will help you.
